# How to print unique words from an inputted string

Tags: python, string, set, python-3.5

I have some code that I intend to print out all the unique words in a string that will be inputted by a user:

```
str1 = input("Please enter a sentence: ")

print("The words in that sentence are: ", str1.split())

unique = set(str1)
print("Here are the unique words in that sentence: ",unique)
```

I can get it to print out the unique letters, but not the unique words.

Comment: Just pass the splitted string to set: `set(str1.split())`

Comment: Thank you, really helps out! ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`String.split(' ')` takes a string and creates a list of elements divided by a space (`' '`).

`set(foo)` takes a collection foo and returns a `set` collection of only the distinct elements in `foo`.

What you want is this: `unique_words = set(str1.split(' '))`

*The default value for the split separator is whitespace. I wanted to show that you can supply your own value to this method.*

Comment: Actually the default value for `split` is *any* whitespace together, which makes for an important difference: `' '.split(' ') == ['','']` but `' '.split() == []`

Comment: Yes, I revised that just a moment ago. Thanks for pointing it out. ;) It seems as though it also removes trailing and leading whitespace. Curious.

Comment: Yes, as I expected, just a simple addition. Thanks for the help! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use:

```
from collections import Counter

str1 = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
words = str1.split(' ')
c = Counter(words)
unique = [w for w in words if c[w] == 1]

print("Unique words: ", unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```py
user_input = input("Input: ").split(' ')

duplicates = []

for i in user_input:
    if i not in duplicates:
        duplicates.append(i)

print(duplicates)
```